# Scroll Bar is not working in ScrollView qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to use a scrollbar inside a scrollview. The scrollbar shows up and I can interact with it (hover/pressed), but it doesn't move, and I can't understand why. I wrote my code by following the official documentation and online examples.

Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

Window {

    width: 740
    height: 580
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#40405f"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            text: qsTr("Menu")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 466
            anchors.topMargin: 74
            onClicked: animationMenu.running = true
        }

        ScrollView {
            id: scrollView
            width: 0
            anchors.left: button.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            clip: true

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle1
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color: "#00000000"
                border.width: 0
                anchors.fill: parent

                PropertyAnimation {
                    id: animationMenu
                    target: scrollView
                    property: "width"
                    to: if(scrollView.width == 0) return 240; else return 0
                    duration: 800
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
                }

                Column {
                    id: columnMenu
                    width: 0
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    spacing: 10

                    Button {
                        id: button1
                        text: qsTr("Button")
                    }

                    Button {
                        id: button2
                        text: qsTr("Button")
                    }

                    Button {
                        id: button3
                        text: qsTr("Button")
                    }

                    Button {
                        id: button4
                        text: qsTr("Button")
                    }
                }
            }

            ScrollBar {
                id: vbar
                hoverEnabled: true
                orientation: Qt.Vertical
                size: scrollView.height / rectangle1.height
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                wheelEnabled: true
                pressed: true
                active: true
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ok, so I edited the code to a smaller version so that it can be run.

Comment: your code has lots of dependency on other files , we cant test it.see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R sorry about that. Since the original code consists of many files and is very large, I though I should just use the problematic part.

Comment: If you write a little example and show problems there it will be great

Comment: what is `scrollView.moving || scrollView.moving`? I see no properties in `ScrollView` with such names. Replace it with `active: hovered || pressed` as in the `ScrollView` doc to test it worked.

Comment: @folibis sorry for the late response, I tried the active: hovered || pressed property it still isn't working.

Comment: Ok, so I advice you to minimize the code as it possible. In my experience most of problems can be found on this step. If no post the code here so we can run and test it.

Comment: @folibis I edited my code, now you can run it. The scroll bar is still not working.

Comment: I don't really understand what is your purpose. Usually scrollbar is used to move a content that is bigger then a container. In your case the container looks bigger. Also the content (the `rectangle1`) has no size so I guess that scrollbar.zise calculation failed. Also I highly recommend not to use hardcoded values and use Layouts/anchors instead.

Comment: I'm working on a desktop application, so the container will have lots of buttons, that's why I'm trying to use a scroll bar, since the active property is set to true I thought that it will always remain active an I can use it. But for some reason it's not even appearing much less doing anything. Also what do u mean by ractangle1 has no size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advices:

1. **Use anchors or Layouts**. Do not use fixed values or some kind of treats, no matter if it works. The long term value of your code will be bad.
2. **You should read carefully the ([ScrollView documentatio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html))**. Also the [Size section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#sizing) and the [Touch and Mouse Interaction Section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#touch-vs-mouse-interaction).

I am able to modify your example without the animation.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

Window {
    width: 740
    height: 580
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#40405f"
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent

            Button {
                id: button
                text: qsTr("Menu")
                width: 100
                height: 50
            }

            ScrollView {
                id: scrollView
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                RowLayout{
                    implicitHeight: 2000
                    implicitWidth: 2000

                    Column {
                        id: columnMenu
                        width: 0
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        spacing: 10

                        Repeater{
                            model: 50
                            delegate:  Button {
                                text: qsTr("Button")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```